# How do you prove that a subset isn't closed under scalar multiplication or addition without using examples?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, how do you prove that the subset  W = {${(x, y, z, w) ∈ R^4 | x + y = zw} $} isn't a subspace without assuming the values of any of its solution vectors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you go to a bank and they ask for an identity proof, what they actually want is for you to provide an identification (an example) which "disproves" their presumption that you are not a random person and hence they conclude that you are a valid account holder. Think over this. The way you "prove" a subsset is not a subspace is by showing that closure under addition/multiplication fails. That is you are claiming the statement that "there exists such elements whose sum is not the subset" . Making a claim is fine. Now , you provide an example (identity proof) and make it valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very weird request, and I’m not sure if you’d even like this approach, but here’s an attempt.

On the left of the equation, you have a linear polynomial, while on the right, you have a quadratic one. So, let us suppose there exists a tuple $(x,y,z,w)\in W$ such that $z\neq 0$ and $w\neq 0$. If this is the case, and if $W$ was closed under scalar multiplication, then for each $t\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $t(x,y,z,w)=(tx,ty,tz,tw)\in W$. But then, this would mean $t(x+y)=t^2zw$, or rearranging, $(zw)t^2-(x+y)t=0$. This equation must hold for all values of $t\in\Bbb{R}$, which is obviously absurd; at most it can hold for two values of $t$ (since the coefficient $zw$ of the quadratic term is non-zero). Actually, you don’t even need the fact that there are at most two solutions, you just need the fact that quadratic grows faster than linear.

Unfortunately, this argument is incomplete, because it rests on the assumption of the existence of a tuple $(x,y,z,w)\in W$ with $w\neq 0$ and $z\neq 0$. One such tuple is of course $(1,0,1,1)$. But since you don’t want explicit examples, this is where I have to stop, and I doubt you can make any further progress. So, the above paragraph is still vacuous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of calculus.

Note that $W$ is the level curve of a function $ f : \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R : (x,y,z,w) \to 
 x+ y -zw.$ The tangent space to $W$ at $(x,y,z,w)$ is therefore a hyperplane which is normal to $ \nabla f = (1,1,-w,-z)$.

We now prove by contradiction that $W$ is not a linear subspace.

Suppose that $W$ is a linear subspace. Then $0 \in W$ and $W$ is equal to its tangent space at $0$. That is $\dim W = 3$ and

$$ W  = \{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb R^4 : x + y = 0 \}. $$

But by definition of $W$, we also have

$$ zw = x + y =  0 \implies  z = 0, w = 0.$$

Hence $$W \subset \{ (x,-x,0,0) : x \in \mathbb R \}.$$ It follows that $\dim W \leq  1$, a contradiction !